# Find elements position amongst its siblings

Tags: javascript

I want to have a function that tells me where the element is relative to every other element.

```js
function Funk(x) {
  var y = //how many elements are infront of it in its parent.
  console.log(y)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>1</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>2</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>3</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>4</li>
</ul>
```

In this example, I want the output to be whatever number I click. So if I click on the third element, it outputs *3*.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to output where the element lies amongst its siblings, not the actual HTML content of the `<li>` itself correct?

Comment: That is what I had a hard time formulating. Thank you, I've improved my title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parentNode` and `children` to go up and down the DOM.

```js
function Funk(x) {
  var y = 0;
  var children = x.parentNode.children;
  while (children[y] !== x) y++;
  y++;
  console.log(y)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>1</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>2</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>3</li>
  <li onclick='Funk(this)'>4</li>
</ul>
```